# How to get drive letter attached to a data disk in Azure?

Tags: azure, virtual-machines, hard-drive

I am trying to get certain details of disks attached to a VM in azure using Azure python SDK. I came to know that:

A VM will have two disks attached to it when created:

1. OS disk (OS disks are attached with a drive letter of C: by default)
2. Temporary disk (Temporary disks are attached with a drive letter of D: by default)

Apart from these we can add extra data disks to a VM, if we need. The problem is when we add a Data disk, we don't know which letter is attached to that disk.

I get the disk utilization details for a disk along with it's drive letter from Azure log analytics but i don't get the disk name in that logs. so, i am not able to identify which disk's utilization logs they are.

Using Azure's Python sdk, I am able to get the disk name and disk size but i am not able to get the Disk letter.

I want to know the letter of a disk so that i get to know the utilization details of a particular disk.
Can someone please help me with this?

Comment: Can you share your code?

Comment: Hi Sumanth, We collect metrics related to disk utilization from log analytics. We also want to know the size of that disk. In log analytics, the metrics we collect are given for a drive letter. we are not able to find the disk name there. We  tried to use computemanagement client of azure python sdk for collecting the size of disks, but there we are able to collect disk name and disk size but not drive letter. Basically, we are not able to associate the utilization metrics we get from loganalytics(available per drive letter) and disk size (available per disk name and not drive letter).

Comment: Hello @KrishnaChaitanya67, I think the only possible way to get a map between the logical drive and data disk to to get the LUN id for that disk . so you can get the lun id in log analytics for the disk drive name as its the perf metrics which is running inside the VM and similarly you can get the LUN id with the data disk name using the python sdk as the details here are provided by Azure resource Manager. But Simultaneously getting both the details would not be possible as one we are getting from inside the VM and other one from outside (Azure resource manager).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As mentioned in the comment , Its not possible to map Azure Disks with Windows Guest Disk in a Single Script.

You can use the LUN for the Disk to get mapping of the two .

**Step -1 :** Remote into the VM , open powershell and run the below command:

```
  `get-disk  | format-list number, path`
```

You will get the list of drives with their drive number (slot) and a path present in your VM.

> For the data disks the path will look something like:
> **?\scsi#disk&ven_msft&prod_virtual_disk#`000001`#{57f56307-b6bf-19d0-94f2-00a0c91efb8b}**

**Note :** The disk#000001# is the LUN part. In this case it's LUN 1.

Or

- Connect to the VM and open Disk Management
- In the lower pane, right-click any of the Disks and choose
  "Properties"
- The LUN will be listed in the "Location" property on the "General"
  tab

**Step -2 :** Now to get the details of the Azure Disks you can run the below
command in **CLI**:

```
  `az vm show -g myResourceGroup -n myVM --query "storageProfile.dataDisks"`
```

Or

**Using Powershell:**

```
$vm = Get-AzVM -ResourceGroupName myResourceGroup -Name myVM
$vm.StorageProfile.DataDisks | ft
```

Or

**Using Python SDK:**

```
from azure.mgmt.compute import ComputeManagementClient
from azure.identity import AzureCliCredential
credential = AzureCliCredential()
rg = 'ResourceGroupName'
name = 'VMName'
subscription_id = "SubID"
compute_client = ComputeManagementClient(credential, subscription_id)
vm = compute_client.virtual_machines.get(rg,name)
##get OS disk size(GB)
print (vm.storage_profile.os_disk.name,vm.storage_profile.os_disk.disk_size_gb)
datadisks = vm.storage_profile.data_disks
##get data disk size(GB)
for i in datadisks:
    print (i.lun,i.name,i.disk_size_gb)
```

**Reference:**

[How to map Azure Disks to Windows VM guest disks - Azure Virtual Machines | Microsoft Docs](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-machines/windows/azure-to-guest-disk-mapping?tabs=azure-powershell)